# Why console not logging variable value?

Tags: javascript, canvas, scope, console

I am trying to make a simple JS canvas line drawing program. When someone clicks on the canvas the first time it is supposed to store its x and y values (variables `x2` and `y2`). And when someone clicks on the canvas a second time it is supposed to store its x and y values of that click in another variable (variables `x1` and `y1`). My problem is that the program is only storing values for the second click, and the console logs the variables as `"undefined"`.

So to sum up, when someone clicks, the `x2` and `y2` values are `"undefined"`, when they should be a number. The main goal is to take the 2 x and y values and make a line with them. Hope someone can help.

**Here is the code I tried:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="350" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>

  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");




    var a = true;

    function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
      let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      let x2;
      let y2;
      let x1;
      let y1;
      if (a) {
        let x2 = event.clientX - rect.left;
        let y2 = event.clientY - rect.top;
        a = false;
      } else {
        let x1 = event.clientX - rect.left;
        let y1 = event.clientY - rect.top;
        a = true;
        ctx.beginPath();



        ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        console.log("Coordinate x1: " + x1,
          "Coordinate y1: " + y1);
        console.log("Coordinate x2: " + x2,
          "Coordinate y2: " + y2);

      }


    }

    let canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

    canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      getMousePosition(canvasElem, e);
    });
  </script>






</body>

</html>
```

-JSman225

Comment: With every call of `getMousePosition()` you define a new pair of `x1`/ `y1` and `x2`/`y2` variables. And, depending on the value of `a` another set of either `x1`/`y1` or `x2`/`y2` variables. Have a look at the different scopes of variables defined with `var` and `let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is that you were defining you variables in multiple places. In order to access them later, you need to store them in main script scope and not inside the function like the `a` variable.

Check this out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="350" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>

  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    var x2, y2, x1, y1;


    var a = true;

    function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
      let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (a) {
        x2 = event.clientX - rect.left;
        y2 = event.clientY - rect.top;
        a = false;
      } else {
        x1 = event.clientX - rect.left;
        y1 = event.clientY - rect.top;
        a = true;
        ctx.beginPath();



        ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        console.log("Coordinate x1: " + x1,
          "Coordinate y1: " + y1);
        console.log("Coordinate x2: " + x2,
          "Coordinate y2: " + y2);

      }


    }

    let canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

    canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      getMousePosition(canvasElem, e);
    });
  </script>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok! Thank you! I am new to `let`'s and this was very helpful!

Comment: I am going to accept the answer, I just have to wait 3 minutes before I can.

Comment: I have added the tags `let`, `const`, `scope` to the question. This should help people easily find it.

Comment: Ok! Sound great!

Answer (score 1):

You are re-initializing the variables inside the event listeners as well. That is why it is undefined in every event call

Below is the updated code you can use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="350" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>

  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");



    let x2;
    let y2;
    let x1;
    let y1;
    var a = true;

    function getMousePosition(canvas, event) {
      let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (a) {
        x2 = event.clientX - rect.left;
        y2 = event.clientY - rect.top;
        a = false;
      } else {
        x1 = event.clientX - rect.left;
        y1 = event.clientY - rect.top;
        a = true;
        ctx.beginPath();



        ctx.moveTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);

        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        console.log("Coordinate x1: " + x1,
          "Coordinate y1: " + y1);
        console.log("Coordinate x2: " + x2,
          "Coordinate y2: " + y2);

      }


    }

    let canvasElem = document.querySelector("canvas");

    canvasElem.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
      getMousePosition(canvasElem, e);
    });
  </script>






</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer too. Your answer is similar to @Nisanth Reddy 's, and he answer first, so I am going to give him the check, but your is very apprciated!